# How to make Preloader in jquery with settimeout?

Tags: jquery

I want a Preloader on the bases of 1 and O variable to change is GIF image which is overlay on background image. if i change variable 1 then show check GIF and if i change variable with 1 then show cross GIF.

```
  var status_val;
  (function( $ )   {
    $(".validation" ).change(function() {
      status_val    =    $(this).val();
      changeStatus(status_val);
  });
  function    changeStatus   (status_val){
    if   ( status_val == 1){
      $('#check, #cross').hide();
      $('#check').show();
      //setTimeout('$("#cross").show()',2000);
    }   else{
      $('#check, #cross').hide();
      $('#cross').show();
      //setTimeout('$("#check").show()',2000); 
    }
  }
  })  (jQuery);
```

Comment: and what is your problem?

Answer (score 1):

```
(function() {
  $('.validation').change(function(){
    changeStatus($(this).val())
  })
})

function changeStatus(val) {
  if (val) {
    $('#check, #cross').hide()
    setTimeout(function(){ $('#check').show() },2000)
  } else {
  $('#check, #cross').hide()
    setTimeout(function(){ $('#cross').show() },2000)
  }
}
```

Read more example about setTimeout() [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Jquery show has a [duration parameter](https://api.jquery.com/show/#show-duration-complete) that determines how long the animation will take

```
 $('#cross').show(2000);
```

Comment: what is the expected behavior, and what behavior you have now?